# How do I make my own custom Ubuntu headless image?

Tags: 18.04, custom-distributions, headless

What are the ways for me to make my own Ubuntu headless image? What I really want to achieve is to create an image that I can burn onto an sd card or emmc and upon first start up on a single computer board, it will have a few applications installed and some scripts to run.

I have been reading up on Yocto and Linux From Scratch (LFS) but I don't really have an idea of how should I be going about doing it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will this single board computer have internet access?

Comment: Yes it will, I need it to be connected to the internet. So there are some stuff that I want to have in this custom build such as nginx and sqlserver and some other applications. 

What I have been doing is installing those applications that I need on one copy of ubuntu server and then I will take out the sd card of that SBC and then clone the image out. I will then burn this image into another sd card whenever another board is needed...

Instead, I would like a distro that I can burn on to the sd card and it runs clean upon every first start up of the SBC...